# how to explicitly reference module in python when using `from <module> import <feature>`

Tags: python

##### i would like to use `<module>.<feature>` when using `from <module> import <feature>` in python .

i would sometimes like to **just import a function or other object instead of the whole module** within my python scripts .

the reason that i would like to expicitly reference the `os` module is that **i believe it is good practice** .
i learned that from [this great video by 'The Cherno'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4NYC-VU-svE) .

this can be done but **the issue is that i can only reference the function but not the module and function as one** , like `<module>.<feature>` .

> for example i have this script :

```py
from os import get_terminal_size

def stretchChar ( char_to_stretch ) :
    if not len ( char_to_stretch ) == 1:
        Exception ( ' "char_to_stretch" must be of length 1 ! ' )
    
    terminal_width = get_terminal_size ( ) # this is where my problem persists .
    
    for i in range ( 0 , terminal_width[0] ):
        print( char_to_stretch, end='' )
    
    print ( '\n' , end='' )

stretchChar ( '-' )
```

> when trying to explicitly reference the module and function like :

```py
from os import get_terminal_size

def stretchChar ( char_to_stretch ) :
    if not len ( char_to_stretch ) == 1:
        Exception ( ' "char_to_stretch" must be of length 1 ! ' )
    
    terminal_width = os.get_terminal_size ( ) # right here i tried to explicitly reference .
    
    for i in range ( 0 , terminal_width[0] ):
        print( char_to_stretch, end='' )
    
    print ( '\n' , end='' )

stretchChar ( '-' )
```

###### and this throws the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joel/revolt-lang/revolt-lang/helper-functions/stretch-char/stretchchar.py", line 14, in <module>
    stretchChar ( '-' )
  File "/home/joel/revolt-lang/revolt-lang/helper-functions/stretch-char/stretchchar.py", line 7, in stretchChar
    terminal_width = os.get_terminal_size ( )
NameError: name 'os' is not defined
```

### does any one know how i can `os.get_terminal_size()` and not import the whole `os` module ?

*Thanks in advance !*

Answer (score 0):

## i solved it , hopefully this will help someone (it won't) .

`os = importlib.__import__("os", fromlist=["get_terminal_size"])`

### then use our function :

`terminal_width = os.get_terminal_size ( ) [ 0 ]`

### note , you must import the `importlib` module .

> finished code goes like :

```py
import importlib

os = importlib.__import__("os", fromlist=["get_terminal_size"])

def stretchChar ( char_to_stretch ) :
    if not len ( char_to_stretch ) == 1:
        Exception ( ' "char_to_stretch" must be of length 1 ! ' )
    
    terminal_width = oss.get_terminal_size ( )
    
    for i in range ( 0 , terminal_width[0] ):
        print( char_to_stretch, end='' )
    
    print ( '\n' , end='' )

stretchChar ( '-' )
```